# Attaching to the Controller Dispatch Event

Tags: zend-framework2

ZF2 question here.

I like the event driven stuff in ZF2.

Here's my goal.

I want to start the session, using a database table, and I want to be thrown to the error/error template if for some reason there is no database connection.

Here are some ways I thought about doing this. I could attach to the application 'route' event and start the session right before the route matching happens, or right after. There are no TRY catches though, in the Mvc\Application.php file so I don't think this is the place to do it.

There IS however a try catch block around the CONTROLLER's dispatch method being called. And I noticed that the controller has it's own internal 'dispatch' event it triggers.

So the other possibility is that I should attach to this internal controller dispatch event and setup my session THEN before the controller's action methods actually execute, and thus before they NEED the session.

So, how can I attach to this internal 'dispatch' method? Or how else can I make it so that any database connection exceptions go to my nice Exception page rather than getting spewed out as a normal php error without any exception handling???

There is no more init() method on the controller because this is functionality events are supposed to provide.

Thank you for the help.

FYI : I tried attaching to different events, such as 'bootstrap', 'loadmodules', 'loadmodules.post'. All I did in the attached method was throw an exception to see if I would end up in the nice error page I have but I didn't have any luck. I ended up debugging it and found this internal controller 'dispatch' method. The controllers get their own internal event manager. At least that's what I gather from my debugging. I might be wrong so correct me please!

Comment: Instead of casting an exception and hoping for the best, you could just take control of the route and dispatch the right controller/action/view (the one with error message) in the catch block.

Comment: I was casting an exception for testing purposes. Zend already catches the exceptions caused by dispatching a controller and routes them automatically. I want to have Zend route me to a nice error page IF the database connection happens to be down.

Comment: When is the database connection failure detected?

Comment: @RobAllen, well it would probably be detected when session_start is called to initiate the database stored session. If there is no database connection then the session start will fail because it can't connect to the database to fetch/write the session.